# New to supervisor - how to make a daemon that works

Tags: python, ubuntu, supervisord

I am new to supervisor.  Below is my supervisor config file.

```
# -*- conf -*-
[include]
files = *.supervisor

[supervisord]
pidfile = /var/run/supervisord.pid

[supervisorctl]
serverurl = unix://supervisord.sock

[unix_http_server]
file = /var/run/supervisord.sock

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface


[program:main]
process_name = main-%(process_num)s
command = /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbTornadoServer/tornadoServer.py --tport %(process_num)s
--port=%(process_num)s
--log_file_prefix=%(here)s/logs/%(program_name)s-%(process_num)s.log
numprocs = 4
numprocs_start = 8050
```

Now, I need to demonize the process where:
1) I can stop the parent proccess and all childs
2) Start
3) Reload all child process
4) If a child fails then automatically restarted.
5) Here is the command line to start

```
supervisord -c /home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtb_supervisor/tornadoSupervisor.conf
```

So...do I use runit? Upstart?

As of now I have kill -9 all parent and child prossess and if I do, the are not respawned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `supervisorctl`, it allows you to start/restart/auto-start/stop processes. If that doesn't fit your needs, you can also communicate with `supervisor` through XML-RPC.

Comment: I did not unstertand supervisorctl.  E.g. how to I stop using stop all using supervisorctl?

Comment: Right from the documentation `supervisorctl stop all`.